# Java Generics, return type to access only protected methods of the abstract type

Tags: java, generics, return-type

I have the following settings in my application

```
//Package 1
public class class1 extends AbstractClass2<class1>{

  public void someMethod(){
    // What i want here is when i call the method "with", I should be able to chain only 
    // the methods defined in AbstractClass3 and not the methods defined in its sub classes.
    with(10).someOtherMethod() // this should be possible (it is possible with the current setup)
    with(10).someMethod() // this should not be possible (it is possible with the current setup)
  }

}

//Package 2
public abstract class AbstractClass2<T> extends AbstractClass3<T>{
  protected void someMethod(){
  }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass3<T>{

  protected T with(int value){
    setValue(value);
    return (T) this;
  }

  protected void someOtherMethod(){
  }

}
```

Basically what i am trying to achieve method chaining, but limit it to the methods defined in the base class "AbstractClass3". How should i achieve this?

Comment: if you set the methods in AbstractClass2 as private you wont me able to call `with(10).someMethod()`.

Comment: Can you make `someMethod()` private?

Comment: No, I should not. Basically the 'with()' method is applicable only for the methods defined in "AbstractClass3<T> and that is the reason i want the method chaining to be limited to methods defined in "AbstractClass3<T>.  If they call "with().someMethod()", the "with()" method will not have any impact on how "someMethod()" behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `with(int value)` and `someOtherMethod()`. And you also do not need generics in `AbstractClass3` (at least in the example you provided).

Your "with" method should be `protected AbstractClass3 with(int value)`. Note that the method now returns a `AbstractClass3`, which means that only methods defined in this class will be available (unless you cast it to a sub-class).

Finally, there is a catchy trick in the method visibility of `someOtherMethod()` which should be public. If you are in a different package, you can only call protected methods through `this.` reference (by inheritance, of course).

I think it's better explained in the code with comments:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass3 {

    protected AbstractClass3 with(int value) {
        // Do stuff.
        return this;
    }

    // If "someOtherMethod()" is protected, you will only be able to call
    // it from sub-classes using "this." reference if you are in a different package.
    // So, we make it public.
    public void someOtherMethod() {
    }

}

public abstract class AbstractClass2<T> extends AbstractClass3 {
    protected void someMethod() {
    }
}

public class Class1 extends AbstractClass2<ANY_CLASS_HERE> {

    public void someMethod() {
        // If someOtherMethod() is protected, this will NOT work because you are not calling it
        // through "this." reference. YOU CAN ONLY CALL PROTECTED METHODS THROUGH "this." reference
        // IF YOU ARE IN A DIFFERENT PACKAGE. As you are calling someOtherMethod() from another 
        // instance returned by "with(10)", that means that you are calling it "outside"; 
        // the "this." reference is "inside" the instance returned by "with(10)". In order for 
        // it to work, someOtherMethod() must be public (or be in the same package).
        // Remember: You need "this." reference to call protected methods in different packages.
        with(10).someOtherMethod();

        // If someOtherMethod() is protected, this works because you are calling
        // it through "this." reference. It's a straight call to the parent.
        this.someOtherMethod(); // Note the "this." reference.

        // ERROR because someMethod() does not exists in AbstractClass3 and "with(10)".
        // returns an AbstractClass3 instance.
        with(10).someMethod();
    }

}
```

I took the generics out of `AbstractClass3` but you can get it back anytime. The important thing here is you understand that your "with" method should return `AbstractClass3` and that protected methods can only be called through `this.` reference if you are in a different package.

Comment: Re: "If you are in a different package, you can only call protected methods through `this.` reference": That's not true; you can call protected methods on any instance of the current type. (That's why the OP's code currently works; without that, it wouldn't compile.)

Comment: You're wrong, @ruakh! Any of these instances you mentioned will (obviously) be a sub-type that will call protected methods through `this.` reference. Just try the code and change `someOtherMethod()` visibility to protected.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're not getting. If `parent.Parent` defines a protected method, then `child.Child` can call that method on *any* instance of `child.Child`. It can literally have `new Child().protectedParentMethod()`.

Comment: @ruakh, no, you can't if you are in a different package. You can learn more about this in Kathy Sierra's certification guide. I took a screenshot for you. Her explanation uses the exact same example you mentioned (parent/child). Check this link: https://ibb.co/Yy0QjtJ

Comment: You mean like `new Class1().someOtherMethod();` inside `Class1`? Yes, it will work since you inherited the member and you can freely use it in "yourself". If that's the case, my bad for misundertanding you.